# Nginx proxy_pass is showing domain 2 url in browser

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have to redirect my domain 1 to another page which is in another domain 2. I have added proxy_pass url in the location block. But the browser shows the domain 2 url, but I need to stay in domain 1 in browser.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to handle a redirect behind the reverse proxy. This is an error_page trick to do it:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 = @handle_redirects;
    }
    location @handle_redirects {
        set $redirect_location "$upstream_http_location";
        proxy_pass $redirect_location;
    }
}
```

Comment: I has been trying many method based on proxy path and tried this snippet as well. But it is getting internal error when tried localhost:80 proxy passed to http://www.google.com